# Data return duplicate after join sql

Tags: sql, join

i want to join both temp table but it return a lot of duplicate data,
below is the result that i get before joining the table.

[image]

Here is after i join both table the result are as below image

[image]

it double up all the data.

I use this sql to join the both table.

```
`       SELECT * FROM(
            SELECT DISTINCT t1.hatch_num AS  hatch_num_1,t1.delay_code AS delay_code_1,t1.st_time + '-' + t1.ed_time AS time_1
            FROM #temp1 t1
        )as a

        CROSS JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT t2.hatch_num AS  hatch_num_2,t2.delay_code AS delay_code_2,t2.st_time + '-' + t2.ed_time AS time_2
            FROM #temp2 t2
        )as b`
```

I tried using inner join, left join but it return the  same result.

here are the #temp1 table sql, when i execute it it return correct data.

```
      SELECT DISTINCT  t1.scn,CONVERT(DATE,t2.opr_st_dt_tm) as work_date,t2.hatch_num,
    t3.delay_code,REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(5),t3.delay_st_dt_tm,108),':','')[time_start],
    REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(5),t3.delay_ed_dt_tm,108),':','')[time_end]
    FROM ccostallysheet t1
    INNER JOIN ccostsitem t2 ON t2.master_id = t1.id
    INNER JOIN ccostsdelayitem t3 ON t3.master_id = t1.id
    WHERE t2.hatch_num = 'H1' AND t2.hatch_num IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY t1.scn,t2.opr_st_dt_tm,t2.hatch_num,t3.delay_code,t3.delay_st_dt_tm,t3.delay_ed_dt_tm
```

AND here are the temp2 sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.scn,CONVERT(DATE,t2.opr_st_dt_tm)as work_date,t2.hatch_num,
t3.delay_code,REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(5),t3.delay_st_dt_tm,108),':','')[time_start],
REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(5),t3.delay_ed_dt_tm,108),':','')[time_end]
FROM ccostallysheet t1
INNER JOIN ccostsitem t2 ON t2.master_id = t1.id
INNER JOIN ccostsdelayitem t3 ON t3.master_id = t1.id
WHERE t2.hatch_num = 'H2' AND t2.hatch_num IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY t1.scn,t2.opr_st_dt_tm,t2.hatch_num,t3.delay_code,t3.delay_st_dt_tm,t3.delay_ed_dt_tm
```

How to join both table without create duplicate result?

Comment: can you provide the data on both  #temp1 and  #temp2

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` combined with `GROUP BY`... And `GROUP BY` but no aggregate functions... How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the tables together on something. I am guessing delay code, so like this:

```
SELECT * FROM(
            SELECT DISTINCT t1.hatch_num AS  hatch_num_1,t1.delay_code AS delay_code_1,t1.st_time + '-' + t1.ed_time AS time_1
            FROM #temp1 t1
        )as a

        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT t2.hatch_num AS  hatch_num_2,t2.delay_code AS delay_code_2,t2.st_time + '-' + t2.ed_time AS time_2
            FROM #temp2 t2
        )as b ON a.delay_code_1 = b.delay_code_2
```

Answer (score 0):

`CROSS JOIN` does exactly what you're getting, that's what it is designed to do. `INNER JOIN` on the other hand should return only some data, but you're not telling it what to return so it is working like a `CROSS JOIN`. Simon gave you an example of how to tell `INNER JOIN` what to return, you need to use `ON` followed by the joining condition. I don't see what the joining condition can be in your case because the information you provided is not enough, so you'll have to figure it out by yourself or give us more details about your two tables and the expected results so we can help you. However, from your description, I get the feeling that what you're looking for is probably `UNION`, not `JOIN`. Try this:

```
SELECT t1.hatch_num, t1.delay_code, t1.st_time + '-' + t1.ed_time AS time
FROM #temp1 t1

UNION

SELECT t2.hatch_num, t2.delay_code, t2.st_time + '-' + t2.ed_time AS time
FROM #temp2 t2
```

Note: you don't need to use `DISTINCT` here, because `UNION` does that automatically for you.